# UTF-8 support in Vi

Tags: utf-8, vi

I am using Solaris 10.

```
#cat /etc/release
                   Oracle Solaris 10 8/11 s10s_u10wos_17b SPARC
  Copyright (c) 1983, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
                            Assembled 23 August 2011
```

It does not have vim. So, I use vi. But, I am finding that vi is not supporting UTF-8 characters. If I open a file containing UTF-8 characters using vi, it's not able to display them. However, tail is working fine. If I tail the content, it's displaying UTF-8 characters. Even, less is working provided I export LESSCHARSET=utf-8.

So, the question is what I need to do set UTF-8 encoding in vi (NOT vim).

Comment: What is the result of :ve (within vi)

Comment: @borrible Version SVR4.0, Solaris 2.5.0

Comment: Is your locale set to UTF-8?  E.g. setting LC_CTYPE to en_US.UTF-8 (outside of vi of course).

Comment: And you are right. The problem is with locale. In the system, en_US.UTF-8 is not even available. When I export en_CA.UTF-8, the UTF-8 characters are visible using vi. Would you mind posting it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set your locale to UTF-8.  E.g. by setting `LC_CTYPE` to `en_US.UTF-8` (outside of vi).

Comment: Note that the environment variable is `LC_CTYPE`, not `LC_TYPE`. Also, the locale value to enable UTF-8 may vary slightly, such as `C.UTF-8`. Use `locale -a` to list available locales.

Comment: @JustinSchell 7+ years for someone to spot the typo!  Fixed.